# WooCommerce Payments error: Not a valid URL

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I made my webshop in WooCommerce with the WooCommerce Payments plugin, but when i am checking out i get the error 'Not a valid URL'.

When i press F12 and go to the console, i see the info below. How can i fix this?

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unrecognized request URL (GET: /v1/payment_intents/pi_3NTtCOCEUdbEABBM1lqRiYGH/confirm). Please see https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

I wanted to check out but it did not succeed

Comment: It looks like you might be passing an invalid `return_url` when you confirm the PaymentIntent. Since you're using WooCommerce Payments plugin, you should reach out to WooCommerce for next steps.

Comment: Yes i now know what is wrong, my return url is a relative path and not a full url. How can i adjust this?

Comment: @Svd Hi, I happened to have the same issues. Were you able to fix it, and share how? Thanks